# Dynamically changing android:drawableEnd/Right on TextView not showing on SDK 4.1

Tags: android, textview

I have my view as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_suburb"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/default_ripple_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/image_one"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/image_one"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

And I change the Right Drawable dynamically.

```
 textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, chooseImageTwo?
            R.drawable.image_two: R.drawable.image_one, 0);
```

It works fine on all version, except on Android Version 4.1. (note, my oldest support version in 4.1). What's the issue?

Comment: try adding textView.requestLayout() and textView.refreshDrawableState() after your set drawable line.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when one have a drawable in the XML, it will not be override by the API call in 4.1. But all other version works well. So just remove the drawable reference as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_suburb"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/default_ripple_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```